# How can I initialise the variable bitmap in the following code?

Tags: java, android-bitmap

I know there is such a question on Stack Overflow
but the answers just don't work in my code.

I have also tried using `decodeStream()` to get 
a bitmap but I just get the same results.

The only method that works is `decodeResource()`.

I can't use `decodeResourse` because I need to
decode constantly changing images that I will get 
at runtime, screenshots

All of the following code is in the `onstartCommand()` method of a service

```
Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentTitle("My notification")
    .setContentText("Hello World!");
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = 
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
startForeground(1,notification);

String path = "/data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/files";
File f = null;
BitmapFactory.Options options = null;
Bitmap bitmap = null;
try{
    //Request Su permission
    Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);
    OutputStream os = sh.getOutputStream();
    //Open an output stream to a private file to my app
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("img4.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    fos.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + 
        "/data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/files/img4.png").getBytes("UTF-8"));
    fos.close();

    f=new File(path,"img4.png");
    options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 4;
    //decodeFile always returns null yet
    //I am sure that the file exsists
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(
        new File(getFilesDir(),"img4.png").getAbsolutePath(),
        options);
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    sh.waitFor();
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
//I create and show a toast
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Exs: " + f.exists() 
//I always get a nullPointerException here
    " "+ bitmap.getPixel(0,0),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Your img4.png contains the string "/system/bin/screencap -p /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/files/img4.png" (because that is what you write to the file). What picture do you expect from this string?

Comment: I definately expect an image to be written to the path "/data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/files" using this line, ("/system/bin/screencap -p " + 
        "/data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/files/img4.png").getBytes("UTF-8"). Let me explain why. Once I have su permission, that line takes a screen shot and stotes it in a certain path. I tried the line ("/system/bin/screencap -p " + 
        "/storage/emulated/0/myscreenshots/img4.png").getBytes("UTF-8") and it wrote a screen shot to the path /storage/emulated/0/myscreenshots. That is why I am replacing the directory to a private location.

Comment: Someone please help.I am open to any questions you may have. This nullPointerException is stressing me.

Comment: It would write an image if you were writing that string to `os` OutputStream (and therefore providing it as command to your `su` shell). As your code stands you write it to `fos`. And that is a `FileOutputStream` with "img4.png" as target.

Comment: Okay. Then explain to me why this line, Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/storage/emulated/0/myimage.jpeg"); also does not create a bitmap yet I manually put a test file(to be absolutely sure that it exsists) into the root of my directory through File manager.

Comment: Let me be more precise on that comment, The exact code I have used is here,

Comment: BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  options.inSampleSize = 4;
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/storage/emulated/0/myimage.jpeg",options);
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"" + (bitmap == null),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: It is in the onCreate method of an activity. The toast is showing null.

Comment: Anyone? No one?

Comment: Unfortunately `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` only gives an error message (on the log) if it cannot find the specified file. In this case as well as if the specified file is not decodeable as an image it just returns null. It is your job to identify the cause (maybe by logging the first 16 bytes of the file) to identify why it could not decode your file.

Comment: Okay. I think we are making some progress. I have found this message in the log;

Comment: 10-20 08:37:54.413 26937 26937 E   BitmapFactory com.mycompany.myapp            Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/myimage.jpeg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: So what do I do about it?

Comment: Are you sure that your applications manifest (main/AndroidManifest.xml) contains the `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and that you have granted this permission on your phone?

Comment: I have not requested for that permission and I dont think I need to.This is the path where the image is located, "/storage/emulated/0/myimage.jpeg". As you can see it is located in internal memory and therefore I do not to ask for any permission explicitly. Something else is wrong here.

Comment: On my old (rooted) phone a sample application worked without this permission. On my newer, not-rooted phone I had to include this permission to make the application work. So please give it a try.

Comment: Wow! It actually worked. Thank you so much Thomas.

Comment: I am new to stack exchange. I cant see where to accept your answer.

Comment: Up till now I just commented on your post - I've added the final conclusion as answer

Comment: I need to ask you another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that your applications manifest (main/AndroidManifest.xml) contains the android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and that you have granted this permission on your phone?

---

On my old (rooted) phone a sample application worked without this permission. On my newer, not-rooted phone I had to include this permission to make the application work.